# Switch font after ToC in memoir

Tags: fonts, sectioning, memoir

I have a long document (thesis) and I would like to use two different fonts. For the first part, containing the front page and table of contents, I would like to use `mathpazo`. After that, I would like to switch to the `default` font of TeX. Here is a MWE showing the structure and where I want to switch:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}  
    Front page

  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage

    %%
    %The default font of LaTeX should be used from here and onwards
    %%

    \section{Main section 1}
    Text ....
    \section{Main section 2}
    Text ....
    \section{Main section 3}
    Text ....1

\end{document}
```

What is the best way to do this? And how do I switch to the normal font after the ToC?

Comment: Mixing two serif fonts so different from each other is really a very dubious thing to do. Note the understatement. `:-;`

Comment: @egreg What do you mean? Is it considered bad practice? Cosmetically, I think it looks nice to have this font on the front page, but maybe there is something else I am not taking into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be not to touch the global font commands by loading `mathpazo` in your preamble.  You can switch the font locally inside a group:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}  

\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}
  \normalfont
  Front page

  \clearpage
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
\endgroup

\section{Main section 1}
Text ....
\section{Main section 2}
Text ....
\section{Main section 3}
Text ....1

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a very elegant solution. Is `pplx` an alias for `mathpazo`?

Comment: @BillyJean - `mathpazo` is the name of the package you load via `\usepackage`, i.e. the file `mathpazo.sty` on your HD.  `pplx` is the name of the font family `mathpazo` loads when the option `sc` is issued.

Comment: Just `\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont` suffices.

Comment: @egreg - Yes, you're right.  Thanks for the reminder.